# Como colocar um código json em textarea html?

Tags: html, json, textarea

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma página que exibe trechos de código em JSON em um textarea, porem já vi em alguns sites que existe algum tipo de plugin para este tipo de exibição como na aba "Erros / Exceções" deste site -> https://m1sandbox.stelo.com.br/ ... gostaria de saber se existe algum plugin ou biblioteca para isto? Agradeço!

Comment: respondi assumindo que você esta tentando implementar com javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tanto pode usar com  o `<textarea>` quanto `<code> <pre>`, no `<textarea>` insira o atributo `readonly` para que não seja possível remover ou inserir caracteres, e no `<code> <pre>` adicione uma borda ao `<pre>` para  "simular visualmente" um `<textarea>`.

Na parte do JSON você deve aplicar o [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp).

Segue exemplos:

```js
var yourObject = {
  "address": {
    "House_Number": 505,
    "Street_Direction": "",
    "Street_Name": "Claremont",
    "Street_Type": "Street",
    "Apt": "15L",
    "Burough": "Brooklyn",
    "State": "NY",
    "Zip": "10451",
    "Phone": "718-777-7777"
  },
  "casehead": 0,
  "adults": [{
    "Last_Name": "Foo",
    "First_Name": "A",
    "Sex": "M",
    "Date_Of_Birth": "01011980"
  }],
  "children": []
};

var textedJson = JSON.stringify(yourObject, null, 4);
document.getElementById("json-area").value=textedJson;
document.getElementById("json-area").readOnly = true; 
document.getElementById("pre-code-area").innerHTML = textedJson;


;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Com tag textarea</h2>
<textarea rows="20" cols="100" id="json-area">

</textarea>

<h2>Com tag code</h2>
<code >
  <pre id="pre-code-area" style="border: 1px solid #7A7A7A;">

  </pre>
</code>
```

Comment: Legal brother.. por enquanto no projeto os dados estão estaticos, fiz com o code+pre direto na html, mais futuramento vou precisar, Agradeço!

Answer (score 2):

com `javascript` você pode transformar um `json` em `texto` usando a função `stringify()`, após a conversão incluia no seu `HTML` normalmente.

```
let json = JSON.stringify({"Language":"PT-BR", "TransactionID":"1234567890"});

const codeArea = document.querySelector('.code-area');
codeArea.innerHTML = json;
```

#### Veja o exemplo:

```js
const raw = {"Language":"PT-BR","TransactionID":"1234567890"};
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const codeArea = document.querySelector('.code-area');
let json = JSON.stringify(raw);


button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  codeArea.innerHTML = json;
});
```

```html
<code class="code-area"></code>
<button class="button">Click</button>
```